# Azure VM + Cloudflare

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, cloudflare

good afternoon!

I know some things about infrastructure, but I'm far from being an expert. I have an Azure VM with some websites, but I wanted to remove this VM from the public world, and instead access the website through a gateway, etc.

I thought about Azure Application Gateway WAF... however, when I finished the deployment, it gave an error saying that the WAF was obsolete and I would have to do it with WAF 2... the problem is that the WAF costs much more. ...

So I thought about Cloudflare, but I don't know anything about it... could you do something with it so that clients can access their urls via Cloudflare and it forwards these requests to the Azure VM via some type of tunnel? Because I wanted to remove direct access to the VM.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your exactly infrastructure, but will try to point you to the right way.

If we imagine that you have one VM with static public IP address, and you want to use Cloudflare for protect site which placed on that VM you need to do next:

1. In the Cloudflare create a [proxied DNS record](https://developers.cloudflare.com/dns/manage-dns-records/reference/proxied-dns-records/) with public IP address of your VM, that means all traffic will go thru via Cloudflare to your VM;
2. In the VM inside, or in the Azure network security group (you need to decide this by yourself), you need to allow traffic only from Cloudflare networks: https://developers.cloudflare.com/fundamentals/concepts/cloudflare-ip-addresses/

Also you can check [Cloudflare tunnel](https://developers.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-one/connections/connect-networks/), maybe it will be suitable here, but I didn't try it.

Comment: Indeed, this seems a good approach! I’ll check this and come back with the results!